# How to append to a stored variable to all delimiters?

Tags: python

I have a variable stored as 
`new_text = text[:start]`. My input file has a ton of delimiters of `~|||~` that I inserted myself. I just want this to be added after each one. I've tried he .join function, but I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: _"I just want this to be added after each one."_ Please clarify. What are "this" and "each one" in this sentence?

Comment: How many times are you going to ask and delete the same question?

Comment: I want "new_text" variable after each delimiter of "~|||~"

Comment: I'm trying to learn man. This is the second time I've posted this, because I can't word it in a way that is clear. I'm sorry, but I'm just here to learn. If you are bothered by it, ignore it, or answer it. Either one will stop me. Thanks.

Comment: Well we don't have a lot of information to go on here. The best way to clarify what you want is to post an example of your input, and your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to add text after every instance of a certain substring, is to use `replace`.

```
data = "Hello~|||~World!~|||~Lorem~|||~Ipsum"
delimiter = "~|||~"
new_text = "ABC"
data = data.replace(delimiter, delimiter+new_text)
print data
```

Result:

```
Hello~|||~ABCWorld!~|||~ABCLorem~|||~ABCIpsum
```

Here, "ABC" has been added to the end of all "~|||~" delimiters.